# Is it logical to give a homepage an alias?

Tags: nodes

Drupal allows us to give a URL alias to any node (`example.com/my-alias`). The "Home page" node is not an exception.

Is it logical to give a homepage an alias?
Shouldn't we just keep it "`/`"? i.e. without an alias?

The question spans over Drupal logic or web building standards, SEO and user experience. I know it might be a bit to broad, but I think it's worth asking.

Comment: `The question spans over Drupal logic or web building standards`. That's right, which means it's not Drupal specific; thus, it's not within the scope for this site. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal core allows to have multiple paths for the same node. In the case of a node assigned as a homepage and with an alias there are at least three paths to access the node.

- /
- /node/123
- /my-alias

No visitors are typically accessing the alternative paths unless you link them in a menu. But crawlers might find them nonetheless. So many site owners consider it as good SEO practice to limit access to one canonical path. The standard Drupal module for this is [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

There is another Drupal-specific issue. Independently of the homepage being a node, it has a built-in alias /index.php. If you visit the site with this alias the links on this page are generated with the base path including /index.php/ which creates a whole bunch of new aliases which can even spill to the non-index.php path via caching. You can prevent this by installing the module Redirect with default settings.